# A person finds it difficult to pray on the last ten nights (Taraweeh)

Tags: ramadan, taraweeh

A person who has a gas problem is finding it difficult to pray on the last ten nights the Taraweeh prayer. What should he do  ?

Please answer quickly since Ramadan is almost over. If you know a sheikh or mufti who can answer this please tell him about this because the prophet said that he who leads others to doing good deeds will get the same amount of merits done by those whom he led to do good deeds

Jazakallahu Khair

Comment: https://youtu.be/ra0kBiBYiFQ- watch this inshallah it will be helpful

Comment: Taraweeh prayer is not necessary so if you don't want to pray you can skip

Comment: "What should a person do?" is a question attracting subjective answers and therefore a bad fit for our site. Especially in case of an optional prayer any answer could fit without clear restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You should not stop praying unless you’re certain you’ve had something come out of you.

It was narrated from ‘Abbaad ibn Tameem that his paternal uncle asked the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) about a man who thought he felt something whilst praying. He said: “He should not stop praying unless he hears a sound or detects an odour.”

Allah knows best.